# PNG Encode producing corrupt image

Tags: image, go, png

I'm reading a framebuffer from a video game console with golang - the buffer is in the format BRGA (which I then convert to RGBA). When I pass the information into the Go PNG Encoder, the image that comes out is not valid. The code i'm using is - where:

> where `data` is a slice of RGBA pixels - 0x398000 in length, `pitch` is 5120, `width` is 1270, and `height` is 720)

```
img := &image.RGBA{
    Pix:    data,
    Stride: pitch,
    Rect:   image.Rect(0, 0, width, height),
}

os.Remove("./img.png")
file, _ := os.Create("./img.png")
defer file.Close()
filewriter := bufio.NewWriter(file)
if err := png.Encode(filewriter, img); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The expected outcome would be: [image: xbox]

But the actual outcome is (only renders on Windows or when view in Chrome.. weird): [image: sad xbox]

I have uploaded a binary dump of the RGBA slice if anybody would like it - https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak-aZ3z7Ea8KwvUsqdP5OgWpZqxsGA

Comment: I'd expect the size of the raw data to be: 1270*720*4 == 3657600 bytes. The size of the provided binary dump is 3768320 (or 0x398000 as you mentioned). Are you sure the data provided is actually just the raw pixel values?

Comment: That length of the dump is the `framebuffersize` given by the Xbox.

Comment: Could you provide more info on how you get the data dump? If it were raw RGBA pixel values your code should work.

Comment: I send the command `screenshot` over TCP to the console, it returns with the response `203- binary response follows`, then the body: `pitch=0x width=0x height=0x format=0x offsetx=0x offsety=0x, framebuffersize=0x sw=0x sh=0x colorspace=0x`. I used that information to read the rest of the response and deseizzle it into the correct pixel format.

Answer (score 1):

You are not flushing the buffered writer. You should do:

```
filewriter := bufio.NewWriter(file)
defer filewriter.Flush()
```

After this fix, I get a valid image:

[image: image produced by program]

Comment: I might be missing something, but that image you posted is exactly the same as the one I posted above, is it not?

Comment: Oh, interesting. On macOS, the image he posted looks completely empty (like a fully transparent image).

Comment: Oh. I noticed something like that too. It renders fine in Chrome (any OS) and on Windows. But on macOS, Safari, and iPhone it's just transparent. Maybe macOS is more strict to the spec when it comes to rendering? Will update original post.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, and I want to comment but can't yet due to reputation, but will add to the Mac OS discrepancy.

The MacOS part of the problem appears to be new, showing up since either the latest 10.12.3 update, or something with Safari. I haven't narrowed down the source yet. But yes, there is something new about how a Mac system will encode/decode an image, causing it to be transparent or grey as a result. A project I am on is also suffering from this problem for the past few weeks and I'm still investigating where it breaks down.